# Div overflow scrolling when -ms-viewport is specified?

Tags: html, css, touch, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

Working on a page that is viewed in Windows Phone 8, and I noticed an odd behavior. When -ms-viewport is specified with a width or height, then it seems like users can no longer use the touch scrolling behaviors on an overflow:auto or -ms-touch-move:pan-y element.

Anyone encounter this behavior, or aware of any workarounds?

edit: Visit this URL on a WP8 device for a repro: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vk7SR/3/show/light

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Comment: I just asked the same question myself and got shot down by a moderator.  He obviously doesn't like Microsoft

Comment: Do you have an example of the bug anywhere?

Comment: @MartinBeeby Visit this URL on a WP8 device for a repro: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vk7SR/3/show/light/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Setting the `@-ms-viewport { width: auto }` may not be acceptable for a number of applications that aspire to present a reactive UI on Windows Phone devices. A working alternative that allows you to set whatever viewport width you desire is to set the following CSS rule:

```
body, html { 
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}
```

I copied the original repro and fix it up with this rule at https://gist.github.com/tjanczuk/7419485. You can also navigate directly to the HTML page with the fix from a Windows Phone device at http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.github.com/tjanczuk/7419485/raw/9a13fc9ad43f2103d8b9e23e25c7b0672a13385f/gistfile1.html

Comment: This saved my day! This should be bountied as is the correct answer!
Both settings `@-ms-viewport` and `-ms-overflow-style` are the key for getting it working correctly!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused for hours what has broken my scrolling div when using @-ms-viewport{width:device-width; height:device-height;}  and your fix did the trick. But on WP8.1 they have broken `device-` dimensions causing bad gaps and redundant areas ... but that's another story.

Comment: Adding:
-ms-overflow-style: none
to my div element already did the trick. Thanks a million, this fixed an issue we've had for a while without us even knowing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width to auto (like below) instead of device-width seems to solve the scrolling issue. I took the source from your page(http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vk7SR/3/show/light/), packaged it as a WP8 app and tried on a Lumia 920.

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: this (http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html) works too!