# Windows Phone 8 IE10 Mobile overflow scroll doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, overflow

I've elements with overflow:'scroll' style setting. All mobile devices but windows phone enables scrolling by touch-drag.

Is there any solution to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

It's because of the viewport setting. Answered on the link below.

[Div overflow scrolling when -ms-viewport is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996387/div-overflow-scrolling-when-ms-viewport-is-specified)