# Windows Phone 8 - Inner div not scrolling even with -ms-overflow-style: none

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8, scroll, ie-mobile

We've got a web app that is giving us a bit of a problem on Windows Phone 8.
Here's a URL for reference: --Removed link--

Last week, scrolling on Windows Phone 8 was working inside the schedule div. This week it isn't. I've spent many hours trying to nail this down and I just can't seem to find the cause. I've gone through removing every piece of MS specific CSS with no change to the scrolling div, I've removed practically every element from the page aside from this scrolling div, also with no change.

I've tried the solutions here: [Div overflow scrolling when -ms-viewport is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996387/div-overflow-scrolling-when-ms-viewport-is-specified)

and here: [Windows Phone 8 IE10 Mobile overflow scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952273/windows-phone-8-ie10-mobile-overflow-scroll-doesnt-work)

and I just can't get the darn thing to scroll.

If you check other browsers or devices, the div will scroll like it's supposed to. Any suggestions would be super helpful.

Thanks

---

Finally figured it out for anyone else running into this issue --

We were using a rule ( -ms-touch-action: none !important; ) to disable double tap zooming which was the first part of the problem.

The second issue was that we had a few containers containing our div that we wanted to scroll. One of the parent containers had a height and overflow: auto, but so did our scrolling div. Removing those rules from one of the two gave us a result that works.