# Windows Phone 8.1 won't scroll scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows-phone-8

I have a user who has contacted me to tell me that a ajax/js populated scrollable div on my website isn't scrollable on Windows Phone 8.1 I've managed to get another Windows Phone user to confirm that the problem exists on a different model.

Unfortunatly, I don't have any emulator tools nor do I have access to a windows phone. So, i'm in a bit of a situation in testing a way to fix this.

Is there a known bug/issue with scrollable divs not scrolling on Windows Phone? And if so, is there a known solution?

My scrollable div structure:

```html
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:472px;width:100%;">
    <!-- ajax'd content -->
    <a href="#nogo" onclick="selectphoto();"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#nogo" onclick="selectphoto();"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#nogo" onclick="selectphoto();"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#nogo" onclick="selectphoto();"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#nogo" onclick="selectphoto();"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <!-- end ajax'd content -->
</div>
```

For those who want to test, here is how.

1. Create an account on http://bit.ly/1Ej6Xx7 (don't worry, it's free)
2. Upload a number of photos using the 'profile uploader' (upload button in your profile)
3. Then go to a forum topic in the forums (we're not going to post anything)
4. Click the 'camera' icon in the 'add comment' box at the bottom
5. Choose 'browse portfolio'. this will open the portfolio browser
6. Try to scroll this box of images. This is what doesn't work.

Comment: Try setting `a{display:block;}` or just `overflow:auto;` instead of `overflow-y:auto;`. This is just wild guess.

Comment: can you post the url to try it out?

Comment: @FlorianMoser I could, but it requires a sign up, uploading a load of photos to my site and then following some steps.

Comment: Can you set overflow explicitly to `scroll` instead of auto? (Also a guess, I don't have access to a windows phone or emulator either.)

Comment: @FlorianMoser I've added some detailed steps above

Comment: @David On my Win10 phone this does work. But there is another issue there: Everytime I scroll to the top and back to the bottom it tries to fetches new photos. After it loaded all and I try again (and it does not find new ones I suppose), the message "No photos found." gets printed out. Got about 20 Messages now after my pictures. I will try on win8.1 emulator

Comment: @David I can reproduce this in the emulator. The user can't scroll while tapping one of the images, but he can when he taps the border of the modal

Comment: @FlorianMoser Thanks for confirming the bug. So, its an issue with 8.1. I wonder why it won't scroll when tapping on of the images. Surely it should be triggering the 'scrolling' action.

Comment: @BSMP I've changed to 'scroll', still no joy

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996387/div-overflow-scrolling-when-ms-viewport-is-specified

Comment: @BSMP It might well be, just reading a few related articles now...

Comment: @FlorianMoser is there a Windows Phone 8.1 emulator for Win 10 Home that I can run? Really could do with testing this before deploying live.

Comment: @David I've been using the emulator included in Visual Studio, but mabye there is a standalone version so you won't have to install the whole package

Comment: @BSMP Unfortunately, the answer from that question didn't work. I'm stuck yet again for a solution.